# Espera WebDriverWait no recoge los cambios en la página web

Tags: python, selenium, web-scrapping, chromedriver

ante todo disculpadme por mi ignorancia supina.
Estoy intentando crear en python un codigo con selenium para hacer unas reservas en una web, pero mi webdriverwait, aunque se espera, no logro que la web se refresque en el proceso y pueda identificar el dato que le indico ( que es un día del mes ) ( que es lo que cambia cada día ).

Os paso el código por si alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo.
Nota: la web actualiza diariamente a las 00:00 el dato que le digo a webdriverwait que espera para continuar y necesito que se identifique en cuanto esté actualizado, porque el exito del código depende de que la actualización sea inmediata:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(0.1)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_uno).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_dos).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_tres).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_cuatro).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_cinco).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_seis).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_siete).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_ocho).click()

paso_nueve = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "07 de"))
)
paso_nueve.click()

*******AQUI SE QUEDA Y NO IDENTIFICA A LAS 00:01 QUE EL DATO YA APARECE EN LA PÁGINA*******

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_diez).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_once).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_doce).click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, paso_trece).click()`